# TypeScript Cast object to another object, still has properties from original type

Tags: typescript, casting, properties

### Problem

I'm having trouble with TypeScript casting.  I am receiving an object of type `B` and I'm attempting to cast that object to type `A`, but also not let the properties from type `B` tag along for the ride.

### Question

Is there a way to do this without referencing the `otherName` property explicitly?  This is obviously a stripped down version of the situation I'm actually in.

```js
export class A {
  id: 0;
  name: '';
}

export class B extends A {
  otherName: '';
}
```

#### For Example:

If I start with something like

```
const b = new B();
const a1 = <A> b;
const a2 = b as A;
console.log(b, a1, a2);
```

results in:

```
{id: 0, name: '', otherName: ''}, {id: 0, name: '', otherName: ''}, {id: 0, name: '', otherName: ''}
```

I'd like, instead, to have something like:

```
{id: 0, name: '', otherName: ''}, {id: 0, name: ''}, {id: 0, name: ''}
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript type system does not affect the actual JavaScript.

Think of it as a hint or tool to help you better understand what's at hand.

If you want to remove properties from an object, consider using utilities like `lodash` or `ramda`.

Comment: Or `Object.assign()`

Comment: I'm aware of the purpose of TypeScript.  I'm looking for something that concisely gives me an object that only adheres to the interface/class I'm casting to.  It's not clear to me how lodash and ramda help me here, but maybe you care to speak to a specific member of these libraries that you are thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash package, we have  a function called "pick" which lets us choose what fields we want to get. For example

> _.pick(object, ["firstField", "secondField"])

Here is a full example:

```
import _ from "lodash";

type TestType = {
        name: string;
        surname: string;
    };

const test: TestType = { name: "n", surname: "s" };
_.pick(test, "name"); // results { name: 'n' }
```

Comment: Please consider adding some information about your code and your findings.

Comment: @Dennis sorry about that first time posting something i will try to put some info to it